# Create new list by adding the elements of three lists together - associated error (PYTHON)

Tags: python, list, append, unpack

I have 3 lists, say:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

b = [0,2,4,6,8]

c = [2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to create a new list which adds the respective elements together, i.e.

```
d = [3,7,11,15,19]
```

**My code:**

```
d = []

for i,j,k in a,b,c:

     d.append(i+j+k)
```

However, I keep getting the error :

> ValueError: too many values to unpack

How do I fix this?

Comment: `for i,j,k in zip(a,b,c):`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try like this:

```
>>> map(sum, zip(a,b,c))
[3, 7, 11, 15, 19]
```

for python 3x you need to call list:

```
>>> list(map(sum, zip(a,b,c)))
[3, 7, 11, 15, 19]
```

Comment: @JoranBeasley yep for python 3 need to call list

Answer (score 1):

While Hackaholic's solution is excellent (and very functional-programming), here's an alternative using list comprehensions.

The key ingredient is `zip(a,b,c)`, which [returns a sequence of tuples containing the ith elements of a, b, c](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).  As Joran Beasley mentions, your code will work just by adding `zip`:

```
d = []
for i,j,k in zip(a,b,c):
     d.append(i+j+k)
```

From here it's pretty easy to get to the list comprehension version:

```
d = [i+j+k for i,j,k in zip(a,b,c)]
```

And in fact you don't even need to unpack the tuple as `i, j, k`, instead you can sum the tuple directly:

```
d = [sum(tup) for tup in zip(a,b,c)]
```